# Express Routing Include Trailing Slash with Wildcard

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a pattern like `/:name/*`, which successfully matches URLs like `/john/` and `/john/smith`. However, it does **not** match the URL `/john` without the trailing slash. How can I make `/john` get matched as well? I tried `/:name/?*`, but that just broke everything.

More specifically, `/:name/?*` matches `/john`, but the `name` parameter only matches with the `j` in `john`, while the `ohn` get captured by the wildcard.

Comment: What version of **express** are you using? `/:name/?*` works fine for me on **v4.16.3**

Comment: I'm using v4.16.0. This behavior is reproducible with http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific. /:name/?* matches /john, but the :name parameter only captures the j, while the wildcard captures the ohn.

Comment: You may use `'/api/:name?/*'` in that case

Comment: @ArifKhan Using `/:name?/*` just results in none of the URL getting matched by `:name`

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to force express to generate a different regex, but you can always provide your own and then extract capture groups from params. Something like this should work: [`app.get(/\/(.*?)($|\/(.*)$)/, (req,res) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(req.params).sort().map(k => req.params[k]);
    const [name, _, rest] = keys; /* ... */` }](https://repl.it/repls/HandyNoxiousExpertise)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so from additional testing, I seem to have gotten `/(:name)($|/*)` to work, but I'm not sure if this is the "correct" or best way to do it, so if anyone else has any ideas, please do chime in.

Comment: I think that is fine, even you can use `/(:name)(/*)?`